# Why is 5-chloro-2-hexene numbered as such when it could be named 2-chloro-4-hexene and have smaller Locants?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

We're learning IUPAC nomenclature of organic compounds and I came across this problem:[image: give the IUPAC name of the following carbon skeleton:]

And it's IUPAC name is:
[image: chemspider]

My question: Why did the numbering start from the left end when starting from the right end would give smaller Locants for the double bond(4) and Cl(2).

Why isn't it called 2-Chloro-4-hexene ?

Comment: An alkene-substituted halide is not the same as a halide-substituted alkene. Double-bonds take priority over halogens.

Comment: @Sam202 so we assign the smallest possible number for the double bond regardless of the position of the sidechain??

Comment: You first identify there are 2 competing functional groups: halide and alkene. Then you determine which has the higher priority (alkene in this case), and number the chain accordingly to give the highest priority group the lowest number possible.

Comment: Please note that, for almost 30 years, the IUPAC name is 5-chlorohex-2-ene and no longer 5-chloro-2-hexene.

Comment: As  Sam202 pointed out, double bond has higher priority than halogens. For example, check the IUPAC name for allyl chloride. It is 3-chloroprop-1-ene. Its never be 1-chloro-prop-2-ene.

Answer (score 3):

The most important simplified criteria for the numbering in such cases are:

1. lower locants for the principal characteristic group that is expressed as suffix
2. lower locants for multiple bonds
3. lower locants for prefixes
4. lower locants for substituents cited first as a prefix in the name

The corresponding actual wording in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

The compound that is given in the question doesn’t have any principal characteristic group that is expressed as a suffix. Thus, Rule (c) is not relevant in this case.

Next, a low locant is assigned to the double bond according to Rule (e). Therefore, the name of the structure without further substituents is hex-2-ene rather than hex-4-ene since the locant 2 for the double bond is lower than 4.

Finally, low locants are given to any substituents that are expressed as prefixes (e.g. ‘chloro’ or ‘methyl’) according to Rule (f). Note that all prefixes are considered together; i.e., there isn’t any order of functional group priorities at this point. In this case, however, there is only one substituent that is expressed as a prefix.

Thus, the correct name is **5-chlorohex-2-ene** (ignoring *E* and *Z* isomers).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you chose to capitalize *rule*?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/64705 ; see also "Capitalization" in the ACS Style Guide.

Comment: … it's also done like this in the Blue Book itself (with a few exceptions).